# Fade in and fade out in popup element

Tags: javascript, fade

I am using a code from this page:
http://green-beast.com/experiments/css_map_pop.php in my website and it works fine. But I am trying to modify the code so that when I hover a "hot spot", the picture (and text) that shows up (to the right) would fade in and then, if the mouse is moved out of the hot spot, would fade out. So far I have managed to make the fade in work, but I can't figure out a way for the fade out to work. I just added

```
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
```

to `ul#cmp li a span.offset` and

```
opacity: 1.0;
transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
```

to `ul#cmp li a:hover span.offset, ul#cmp li a:focus span.offset, ul#cmp li a:active span.offset`.

Now when I hover a hot spot, it will fade in, but again when I move out of the hot spot, it does not fade out.

Can someone please show me how to achieve what I want? I have tried several things but with no success.

Thank you.

I have put the code from the page in a jsfiddle so it would be easy to make experiments. The first part of the CSS, called "Experiments Global CSS", is not of interest, IMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/fidnut/r52kkrbw/

Comment: I think the issue could be with the margin positions (-9000px) on the 'ul#cmp li a span.offset' selector. The fade is probably occurring, its just off screen. I can't seem to adjust the other CSS to make it stay.

Comment: I don't think it can be done. Once you move off the hotspot the area moves position. Implementing a fade before the move with CSS may not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the fact you are changing the position (at first this is at margin -9999 or something, after you're not on hover, it will return to that margin - you won't see it fade away, you can animate the position, or not use it...)

I've fiddled with it a bit, so you can see the fade out in action...

```
ul#cmp li a span.offset { 
   // margin-top : -9000px;
   //margin-left : -9000p
   position : absolute;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
 }
```

[fiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/q4n5ru7g/)